# How to select rows based on median value in R?

Tags: r, median

I am quite new to R and cannot figure this one out. Let’s say I have a data frame with four columns. The first column determines group membership, the second column should be used for filtering and the two last columns should just follow along. It will look like below:

```
> test.data
group filter a b
first      1 1 2
first      2 3 1
first      3 2 3
second     1 2 1
second     2 2 5
second     3 3 1
second     4 3 1
```

For each group, I would like to calculate the median in the filter column. The same rows should then be used in column a and b to, when necessary, calculate the mean of the two rows or just return the one row if number of rows is odd.

The result should be:

```
group filter     a     b
first      2     3     1
second   2.5   2.5     3
```

When using dplyr, I can calculate the median of each column independently of the filter column, but not with regard to the filter column:

```
median.data <- test.data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_all(funs(median))
> median.data
group filter     a     b
first    2.0   2.0     2
second   2.5   2.5     1
```

When using tapply, I can calculate the median, but don't know how to also take the other columns into account:

```
median.data <- tapply(test.data$filter, test.data$group, median)
> median.data
first second 
2.0   2.5
```

Then I figured that I should try to write a function myself that performs the steps below.

for each group:

1. order by column "filter"
2. extract middle row, two rows if even
3. calculate mean

But then I got stuck on how to find the middle (or two middle) rows...

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!